# Insert this in a function jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, this

I'm using classes in my function because I want to duplicate my block. I want to put (this) in the function but as I'm using 2 buttons with differents classes I need to something like:

```
 $('.scroll-down')"(THIS)".mouseenter...
```

Here's my current JS (fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bq7Ub/):

```
$(function() {
    var ele   = $('.scroll');
    var speed = 25, scroll = 5, scrolling;


    $('.scroll-up').mouseenter(function() {
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
        }, speed);
    });


    $('.scroll-down').mouseenter(function() {
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
        }, speed);
    });


    $('.scroll-up, .scroll-down').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            if (scrolling) {
                window.clearInterval(scrolling);
                scrolling = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I can't figure out how to do this, please help.

Comment: Please improve the description, otherwise we won't be able to figure it out either. I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: As Jon said. Either that or can you supply us with a link to the website so we can get an idea of what you're aiming for.

Comment: Here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/bq7Ub/

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, but have you tried: `$('.scroll-down').on('mouseenter', function(){ /* do stuff here, 'this' is the current element */ console.log(this); });`

Comment: sorry, i didn't finish my question

Comment: there's the code folks, some help please.  http://jsfiddle.net/bq7Ub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to get the nearest `.scroll` to the hovered controls. Currently you're scrolling all `.scroll` elements by using `$('.scroll')`.

Remove `var ele = $('.scroll');` and add `var ele = $(this).parent().prev('.scroll');` to your event handlers:

```
$('.scroll-up').mouseenter(function () {
    var ele = $(this).parent().prev('.scroll');
    scrolling = window.setInterval(function () {
        ele.scrollTop(ele.scrollTop() - scroll);
    }, speed);
});

$('.scroll-down').mouseenter(function () {
    var ele = $(this).parent().prev('.scroll');
    scrolling = window.setInterval(function () {
        ele.scrollTop(ele.scrollTop() + scroll);
    }, speed);
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/bq7Ub/4/

Answer (score 1):

I would say, give an `id` to the scrolling elements and make the `.control` elements (*should also be class since they are not unique*) relate to those with a `data-for="the-id-of-the-scrolling-element"`.

```
<div class="scroll" id="scroll-1">
bla bla...
</div>
<div class="control" data-for="scroll-1">
   ...
</div>
```

and just use

```
// delegate handling of mouseenter for both up/down to the .control element
$('.control').on('mouseenter','.scroll-up,.scroll-down',function(){

   var targetId = '#' + $(this).closest('.control').data('for'),
       target = $(targetId),
       self = $(this),
       actualScroll = self.is('.scroll-up')?scroll*-1:scroll;

    scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
        target.scrollTop( target.scrollTop() + actualScroll );
    }, speed);

});
```

for the event handling..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bq7Ub/5/

Comment: @novoa, glad it worked.. You can accept/upvote if you use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of the functionality you asked for http://jsfiddle.net/h5pnJ/1

```
<div class="scroll-container">
<div class="scroll">
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here<br /><br />
Content here and more content here
</div>
<div id="control">
<a href="#" class="scroll-down">Down</a> - <a href="#" class="scroll-up">Up</a>
</div>
</div>


$('.scroll-up').mouseenter(function(e) {
    scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
        var scrollElement = $(e.target).parents('.scroll-container').find('.scroll').first();
        scrollElement.scrollTop( scrollElement.scrollTop() - scroll );
    }, speed);
});
```

I've added a container so that I can get hold of the scroll element specific to that container. This can be extended to any number of scrolling sections you want without editing the js code. Instead add the html with proper container.

There are many more ways to do this. But this is the quick solution you can use to get it working.